# System able to connect to mysql docker, but other docker container cannot

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'admindb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secretpassword'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'someverysecretpassword'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
      - '33060:33060'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - adminnet
  app:
    image: "node:latest"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    user: "node"
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /home/app
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/../:/home/app
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    command: "npm start"
    networks:
      - adminnet
volumes:
  db:
  data:

networks:
  adminnet:
```

And this is my app.js:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('admindb', 'admin', 'secretpassword', {
    host: 'mysql',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

When I just run the MySQL container (so, if I remove the "app" instance from the docker-compose file) and replace `host:'mysql'` with `host:'127.0.0.1'` and run `npm start` from my host machine, it is able to successfully connect to the database, which runs from the container.

But if I run app.js from a container, which should connect to the database inside the other container, it doesn't work. I use `host:'mysql'`, but I keep getting the following error:

```
containers-app-1    | Unable to connect to the database: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
containers-app-1    |     at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
containers-app-1    |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
containers-app-1    |     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)
containers-app-1    |     at async /home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
containers-app-1    |     at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
containers-app-1    |     at async /home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:301:26
containers-app-1    |     at async Sequelize.authenticate (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:453:5) {
containers-app-1    |   parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
containers-app-1    |       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
containers-app-1    |       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
containers-app-1    |       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
containers-app-1    |     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
containers-app-1    |     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
containers-app-1    |     syscall: 'connect',
containers-app-1    |     fatal: true
containers-app-1    |   },
containers-app-1    |   original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
containers-app-1    |       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
containers-app-1    |       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
containers-app-1    |       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
containers-app-1    |     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
containers-app-1    |     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
containers-app-1    |     syscall: 'connect',
containers-app-1    |     fatal: true
containers-app-1    |   }
containers-app-1    | }
```

Something makes it impossible for the node-container to connect to the database inside the mysql-container. I tried to use ping from the node-container, but that package isn't available.

I read a ton of webpages and I'm debugging for the past few hours, without luck. Anyone who might know the issue? I already tried all similar StackOverflow questions and solutions, without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your stack on my machine and I got it working successfully, after a second run. I ran it twice because of your `depends_on` option (see my notes below).

Here's my machine specs:

**Machine:** MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
**OS:** macOS Monterey v12.4
**Docker Version:** 20.10.12 (installed with their .dmg)
**Docker Compose Version:** not used -- the latest version of docker includes it as a subcommand

And here's a git repo with my working copy of your app:
https://github.com/CodyEakins/question-73053680

I think this problem has multiple causes:

1. Your `docker-compose.yml` file's `depends_on` option. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) on `depends_on`, you'll see that your `app` service DOES NOT wait for `mysql` to be healthy before attempting a connection. You have to use the [`healthcheck` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) if you want to make sure `mysql` is healthy before connecting.
2. There is a problem with your docker's internal host networking on your machine. This is hard to diagnose without knowing what OS you're using or what version of Docker you're running.
3. If you're using swarm mode with Docker, local bind mounts for volumes can be problematic/buggy. Not recommended.

**P.S.** - I also made some slight changes to your `docker-compose.yml` file inside my repo, namely regarding how you bind mount your app's package inside the container. Checkout my `app` service's `volumes` option ([link](https://github.com/CodyEakins/question-73053680/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L27)) vs your own.

Try cloning my repo in a separate directory. Build/run it, and let me know the results. You may have to use `docker system prune` to make sure there are no conflicts with my stack instance vs your stack instance.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Adding the healthcheck is a very good idea! I'll try that. And you're right that the problem was with my internal host networking... I'm working on an Arch Linux system, and nftables keep screwing with my iptables. Same this time. Still looking for a way to delete nftables from the system, or disable them

Comment: I tried your files in a different folder and that's how I figured something had to be wrong with my docker networking, and after flushing the nft tables (again) everything worked fine. So I'll look for a way to make sure only iptables are being used instead of nftables.

Comment: Guess `sudo pacman -Rcns nftables` just did the trick

Comment: I would look into what Docker's installation requirements are for Arch Linux. I'd hate for you to nuke part of your system's network just to get this running. I mean, if it helps you get the job done, then no worries, but this has implications if you intend to run this app in the cloud/in production. 

But glad you got it working. Happy developing!

Comment: The documentation of Arch Linux already mentioned nftables could screw up the docker installation, and docker doesn't support nftables. I don't use nftables personally, at least I'm not sure what for, I'm fine using iptables. Guess it was already there from the beginning. At least now it works on both my machine as well as my NAS :) And my internet and stuff still works. So far so good.